# PDF is not loading only on iOS mobile device (Cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova, safari, pdf.js, react-pdf

```
import { pdfjs , Document, Page } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack'; // it already has pdf worker

<Document 
      file={url}  
          onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
          onSourceError={error => onDocumentSourceError(error)}
          onLoadError={error => onDocumentLoadError(error)}>
       <Page onLoadError={error => onPageLoadError(error)}
       pageNumber={pageNumber} />
</Document>
```

Everything is fine with local files.

External pdf file works on Chrome Desktop, Safari desktop.
External pdf file works on Android Device (Cordova).

**External pdf file is not working on iOS device (Cordova).**

The error I got onDocumentLoadError:
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.body.getReader').

Comment: iOS probably wont allow opening pdf from inapp browser due to security constraints... why dont you try checking pdf viewer cordova plugins

Comment: Its end up with PDF.js on Android and InappBrowser for iOS with custom extra php page to display PDF.